# close button in lytebox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Close button is not working in the lyte box,while the link is working but i want button instead of link there by i can easily apply css to my button.
thank u

Comment: Care to post some relevant code?

Comment: Post some code of your lytebox and explain about your problem!

Comment: for that matter, why are both jQuery and dojo tagged here when there's currently no evidence pointing to use of either?

Comment: retagged without jquery and dojo

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but by the sounds of it you want to style the close 'button' with css. You say the link still works, do you mean there is a link with the text 'Close'? If so then there is probably a problem with your image linking. Either way you can still style that link it has the id 'lbClose'.

```
a#lbClose {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the lytebox close button is not a real button but a hyperlink. To use a button instead of a link, you would have to change the lytebox code (Which you most certainly can). Or, you could set the close button to not display (there is a property you can set to false in the lytebox.js: this.showClose) and in your iFrame code add a button to do whatever you need it to do.